# How to change 1 line of text with existing entries split to multiple lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

RHEL 7 system.
I have an output file that looks like

```
eDTG=20210210-1540
Sent     74004956
Completed     72185529 (97.54%)
Lost     18119427 (2.46%)
QPS, SERVFAIL QPS     60122 2905
eDTG=20210210-1601
```

I've been using sed to change the spacing to tabs for saving as a csv. Now it turns out we need to break the QPS line to 2 separate lines to look like this (note the numbers split between the lines)

```
eDTG=20210210-1540
Sent     74004956
Completed     72185529 (97.54%)
Lost     18119427 (2.46%)
QPS     60122
SERVFAIL QPS     2905    
eDTG=20210210-1601
```

I can do this with

`awk '/QPS/ {printf "QPS\t%s\nSERVFAIL QPS\t%s",$4,$5}' output.txt`

But gawk -i inplace is not available so i have the issue with writing to another file. Well of course it only printed the matched line if i didn't put in the `; {print}`
option. And then it writes the old line as well. I know there has to be a better way to do this than creating the second file and then copying it back to the first filename (cutting the QPS, ...). I would appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: `gawk -i inplace` also use temporary file for the inplace job and `sed -i` as well

Comment: `awk '/^QPS,/ {printf "QPS\t%s\nSERVFAIL QPS\t%s\n",$4,$5;next} 1' output.txt > output.txt.1 && mv output.txt.1 output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

*sed* could help you more.

```
sed -E -i 's/^QPS,[[:space:]]+SERVFAIL QPS[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+$)/QPS\t \1\nSERVFAIL QPS\t \2/' file.txt
```

the  *-i* flags make the sobstitution in place.

Comment: Your substitution is not tab separated as OP needs.

Comment: [gnu-sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions) says: **Space characters: in the ‘C’ locale, this is tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.**

Comment: The substitution is not a regular expresion.

Comment: Yes ur right. I've edited

Comment: As pointed out in a comment under the question, the `-i` option does indeed use a temporary file, which OP doesn't seem to like. However, it is unlikely that there is a tool that can perform this task without temporary storage.

Comment: I understand the -i use does the intermediate file, i was just saying i didn't want to manually handle this with an intermediate file.

I apologize for the delay in responding i ended up calling out sick today and spent it in bed.